# cpp: can't get the value of member via pointer by using ->

Tags: c++, class, shared-ptr, member

I have a question about how to use the **->** in **cpp**. What I need to do is get the private member value **code** of class B by using a pointer **a** created in class C, my code has a structure like this:
I paste the original code here:

```
//detector.hpp
class Detector{
public:
  std::string name;
  int code;
}

//detectorH.hpp
class detectorH : public Detector {
private:
  std::string name;
  int code;
public:
  detectorH();
std::shared_ptr<Detector> h_detector();
}

//detectorH.cpp
detectorH::detectorH(){
  name = "h";
  code = 1111;
}
std::shared_ptr<Detector> h_detector(){
  return std::make_shared<detectorH>();
}

//findCode.cpp
class findCode{
private:
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Detector>> detectors;
public:
  findCode(){
   detectors.push_back(h_detector());
  void find(){
   for(auto& d:detectors){
     std::cout << d->code << std::endl;
   }
  }
 }
};
```

But the problem is the **cout** is always 0, meaning that I've failed to get the right value. I don't know why...and there is no bug message so I don't know how I can fix it... Anyone can give my a hint? Thanks a lot!

Comment: `As.push_back(B());` is wrong. `B()` doesn't return a pointer, it returns an object.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for your reply! yes B() returns one object, and i think push_back(B()) is for adding objects into the vector As?

Comment: @Barmar And every object has a member **code**, which could be visited by a pointer **a** of vector **As**??

Comment: `B:B(){` is a syntax error. Please copy and paste your real code.

Comment: @M.M ok, wait a minite

Comment: Only the code in `B` can access `B`'s private members. That's what private means. Also, `A`'s `code` is completely separate from `B`'s `code` even though you've given the same name. Variables can't be overridden.

Comment: @immibis so I need to set the code in B as public member?

Comment: @Elsa You don't *need* to do anything... except for breathe and eat and sleep. You might need to change the code *in order to do something else* but since I don't know what the something else is, I can't help you there.

Comment: @immibis sorry I meant: I've changed the **code** as public member of **B** but it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Only the code in B can access B's private members. That's what private means. Also, A's code is completely separate from B's code even though you've given the same name. Variables can't be overridden.

Comment: ^ I reposted my last comment since you didn't read all of it.

Comment: @immibis I‘ve deleted **code** in **B**, and it works! thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commenters said - `code` in `A` has nothing to do with `code` in `B`. Moreover when you access `code` via pointer to `A` you access `A::code`. As we don't really know what you want to achieve you can for example remove `code` from `B`:

```
class A {
public:
    int code;
};

class B : public A {
public:
    B() { code = 1111 };
};
```

or initialize it to some value:

```
class A {
public:
    A() : code{ 2222 } { }
    int code;
};

class B : public A {
public:
    B() : code{ 1111 } { }
private:
    int code;
};
```

You can do it also in `B`'s constructor:

```
class B : public A {
public:
    B() : code{ 1111 } { A::code = 2222; }
private:
    int code;
};
```

Comment: thank you! see your answer right after having changed my code~ you are right! so as @immibis , thank you very much!